# The last label on xaxis disappears partly in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, label, axis, axis-labels

As I am forcing Highcharts to show the last label on the xaxis, this last label is partially hidden, or partly disappears:

[image: Highcharts last xaxis label partly hidden]

Why is that? And what can I do? Setting the »marginRight« in the »chart« settings does not do the trick.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Hi @luftikus143, Could you show the problem in some online code editor? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: @ppotaczek: here is finally [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/15mwhdvk/3/)

Comment: Hi @luftikus143, Thanks for the example. Probably that is a Highcharts bug. Do you need to enable `endOnTick` option?

Comment: @ppotaczek: If there is no workaround, then I must deactivate the endOnTick, but which looks strange, as not 2020 is shown, but 2016, although data go way until 2019. Thanks for having looked at this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `align: 'right'` attribute for the last label:

```
      chart: {
          events: {
              render: function() {
                  var ticks = this.xAxis[0].ticks;

                  Highcharts.objectEach(ticks, function(tick) {
                      if (tick.isLast && tick.label.xy.opacity) {
                          tick.label.attr({
                              align: 'right'
                          });
                      }
                  });
              }
          }
      }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tv5f0x2a/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.objectEach%3CT%3E

Answer (score 0):

This might be the chart container width being too small, or the chart itself is too small.

You should try:

1. have you tried changing chart width? https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.width
2. try making the container for the chart wider